# when player hits on a wall it starts bouncing, how to make player move properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Accelerometer : MonoBehaviour {

public Vector3 positionplayer;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
     transform.Translate(Input.acceleration.x, 0, -Input.acceleration.z);
     transform.Rotate (0,0,0);
}

}
```

i have attached this script to the player,every thing is working fine but when it hits an obstacle it starts bouncing..but it doesn't bounce on the ground(only when the wall is hit)

i have made the ground using plane and four walls using cube

For player  have added a collider, rigid body and set rigidbody to gravity with mass 1

for the walls i have added box collider and just a rigidbody

this in my new code

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections;

public class Accelerometer : MonoBehaviour {

public Vector3 positionplayer;
Rigidbody b;
public float speed = 10.0f;
private Quaternion localRotation;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

 localRotation = transform.rotation;

 }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{

float curSpeed = Time.deltaTime * speed;

//transform.Translate(Input.acceleration.x, 0, -Input.acceleration.z);

transform.position += (transform.right * Input.acceleration.x) * curSpeed;

transform.position += (transform.forward * -Input.acceleration.z) * curSpeed;

//transform.Rotate (Input.acceleration.x,0,0);



localRotation.z += -Input.acceleration.z * curSpeed;
localRotation.z += Input.acceleration.z * curSpeed;

//transform.rotation = localRotation;

print (transform.position);
}
}
```

Comment: This may not be relevant to your situation but if you don't want your transform to rotate you should check the settings in the rigidbody so that those values don't change.  It separates it by x/y/z coordinates so you can be specific with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few things you can try:

- Remove `rigidbody` from walls
- move your player using `rigidBody` component instead of `transform.Translate`.

Here is a sample code from [Unity Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/earn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/moving-the-player):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    Rigidbody rigidbody;

    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rigidbody.velocity = movement * speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: when i added this script to the player ,the playeris not moving at all

Comment: @Umair_M i have a new script given in my que...it actualy works except rotation,why the rotation is not working

Comment: You are using Quaternion. And its w,x,y,z components are not to be used as traditional x,y,z rotation. Use EulerAngles instead. Just like in my answer.

Comment: For player to move, you need to set the xMin,xMax, zMin, zMax values from inspector to give a boundary to move in.

Comment: @Umair_m can u provide a reference which uses xMin,xMax, zMin, zMax values ,i am new to this unity and actually dont know more about it.

Comment: you can follow the tutorial link I gave you in answer. By the way you dont need to clamp you player so you can remove rigidbody.Position part. I am going to update the code in answer